# gnu sort/uniq: sorting by number of times

Tags: sorting, uniq

How can I use GNU `sort` and `uniq` to have the most common occurrences on top instead of numerical or alphanumerical sorting? Example `list.txt`:

```
1
2
2
2
3
3
```

Since '2' occurs 3 times, should be on top, followed by '3' and '1' like this:

```
$ cat list.txt | "some sort/uniq magic combo"
2
3
1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
cat list.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

The `-c` includes the count of each unique line and then you sort by that.

If you want to remove the count after sorting, do so:

```
cat list.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | awk '{ print $2; }'
```

Comment: I've been doing this for ages, and for moderate size tasks it works well.  However every so often I find myself with gigabytes of log data to go through and doing a sort on that requires a lot of disk space that is for duplicate lines that you throw away in the next step.  There are better algorithms, but I don't know good simple command line tools for solving this problem at a larger scale.